# Microtype and word spacing

Tags: spacing, microtype

I'm trying to change the default word spacing for some font.  I know 2 ways to do it: setting `\fontdimen`s or `\spaceskip`.  With these approaches and `microtype`'s `\textls` I get two different results, none of them satisfactory.  How can I get the same (increased) interword space inside letterspaced text and between it and regular text?

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\def\test#1{{#1\relax
\textls[200]{test test} test test\par}}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\test{}
\test{\spaceskip 10pt}
\test{\spaceskip 0pt\fontdimen2\font 10pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm not quite following, but what is your desired outcome?

Comment: 1. Increase default interword space; 2. increase letterspace locally; 3. get equal interword spaces

Comment: Note the fontdimen setting is global

Comment: Yes, I know it.  In real work I set it for the whole document from the very beginning.  But microtype seems to be using something else for its calculations.

Comment: Why would you want to change the interword spacing, normally the dimension loaded from the font metrics is just right for the maximum readability. If you want to make your document look longer, consider increasing `\linespread`.

Comment: One possible reason to change default spacing: different languages have different mean character width (e.g. in Russian we don't have "i" or "l").

Answer (score 3):

The question has multiple non specified assumptions. But in case you want to increase the default *interword* space, use XeTeX. See section 7.3 of fontspec's manual.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\addfontfeature{WordSpace=10}
\kant[1]
\textit{\kant[1]}
\end{document}
```